# Can I avoid constructor

Tags: java, oop

sometimes I reason some basic stuff. This time for instance, can I avoid constructor in java with following,

*please consider that I understand that default constructor will be provided by jvm anyway*

```
    class TestConstructor {

private String cusName;
private String dbConnectionURL;
private Customer cus;

// avoiding constructor through this init method
public void init(String cusName, String dbConnectionURL, Customer cus) {
    this.cus = cus;
    this.dbConnectionURL = dbConnectionURL;
    this.cusName = cusName;
}

public boolean connectToDatabase(some parameter)

    // some code may be to connect to database  

    return connectionSuccessful;
}

public boolean isCustomerSatisfied() {

    // some code to perform some operation

}

// some more methods to do more stuff
```

and then I can initialize the class and use the class in following way ?

```
TestConstructor tc = new TestConstructor(); 
tc.init("John", "db connection string", new Customer(x, y, z));
tc.connectToDatabase(required args go here);
tc.isCustomerSatisfied(required args go here);
```

the only issue I can think is that you could call init on the same constructor and change values of the object.. which is a security issue and the most major one perhaps.

But is there anything else ?

Pardon me if its a bad question. Just came to my head

**Actually I have been preparing for the interview and was thinking what if I was asked such a question - "what constructor does can be achieved this way then why do you need constructor?" following which I started thinking of it**

**I am surprised that most people are clinging onto 'you used static' .. the code was just the sample to give an idea. The real question was that you could avoid constructor but can you get away with it ? what are the downsides**

Comment: using static method means it requires a static fields

Comment: not sure if you're thinking the right thing. the fact that you've called `new TestConstructor()` meant you've called the constructor? The only difference is that you could not to initialize your class during constructor.

Comment: Did you actually try to compile this? Did you not get compile errors attempting to reference `this` in a static method?

Comment: i have updated it to take out static. that was a mistake but what about now ? I understand there is not much difference and you wouldn't do it. But I was just wondering of any downsides other than what I have mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to `this` in a static method (your `init` method), since a static method has no access to an instance of the class (unless you pass it such an instance as an argument).

If you want to create an instance with the default constructor and initialize its members with the `init` method, remove the `static` keyword.

Other than the issue of the static method, you can certainly use a non-constructor method to initialize the instance. However, what do you gain here? The call to the init method looks the same as a constructor with arguments. The main difference is that, as you mentioned, you can call this init method multiple times.

Comment: The OP edited the question to remove `static` from the signature

Comment: @Whymarrh Well, the last paragraph answers the question with the assumption that the static keyword would be removed.

Comment: Another difference is, that if you use an empty constructor and then call the init method there is a time where the object might be in an invalid state, which should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You appear be trying to create a "factory method".

The following version is incorrect (it won't compile!) because a `static` method cannot use `this`.  Also, you are not returning an instance.

```
public static void init(String cusName, String dbConnectionURL, Customer cus) {
    this.cus = cus;
    this.dbConnectionURL = dbConnectionURL;
    this.cusName = cusName;
}
```

But if you wrote it as follows, it should work:

```
public static TestConstructor init(String cusName, String dbConnectionURL, 
                                   Customer cus) {
    TestConstructor res = new TestConstructor();
    res.cus = cus;
    res.dbConnectionURL = dbConnectionURL;
    res.cusName = cusName;
    return res;
}
```

---

The other way to make that method "work" would be to change the fields to `static`.  But then there will only be one set of variables ... shared by all threads that use the class, etcetera. On the other hand, that *might* be what you are trying to achieve.

---

The third possibility is that you intend to use the `init` method to initialize the object after construction; e.g.

```
public TestConstructor() { }

public void init(String cusName, String dbConnectionURL, Customer cus) {
    this.cus = cus;
    this.dbConnectionURL = dbConnectionURL;
    this.cusName = cusName;
}
```

then

```
TestConstructor tc = new TestConstructor();
tc.init("fred", someURL, someCustomer);
```

That works ... but I don't see any great advantage in doing that.  And the disadvantage is that your `TestConstructor` objects are constructed in an uninitialized / partially initialized state ... which is bad from the "abstraction" perspective.

---

> The real question was that you could avoid constructor but can you get away with it ? what are the downsides

Yes you can.

One downside is that if you have `final` instance variables, the can only be initialized in a constructor (or an initializer block which runs *before* the constructor code).  Factory methods and `final` instance variables that depend on parameters don't mix.  The same applies to the `init` method that is called on a newly constructed instance.

But there are upsides too.  For instance the factory method could be an instance method of a factory object, and that allows you to get around some of the issues of using `new`.  (For example, that you can only `new` a specific class.)

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, that's what the JVM does behind the scenes - there's even a method named '' that corresponds to the constructor. However, constructors aren't there to just help out with setting the parameters, they're there so that the system can guarantee that some parameters (or a valid combination of them) has been set.